Which Carebears series had Mimi in it
I think her name is Mimi. From what I remember of the series of carebears, there was this dark dimension and the bad guy was a cloaked guy and he had a minion called Pugsley (think that's how you spell his name).
When it comes to Mimi, from what i can remember she was the bad guy's niece who had had a scream that would break glass and he was deadly terrified of her screaming and now and again her and Pugsley would be sent off on this bike thing with propellers.....also i think she was very very ticklish

Do you mean Shreeky? 

She's Lord No Heart's niece who has the ability to "emit very loud and unpleasant vocal 'shrieks'". She appears in the original TV series when it was produced by Nelvana (1986-1988).

yeh that's her, i remember how she looks cause she reminded me a lot of Susan from Diskworld with that streak in her hair, i must have called her Mimi when i was young because i couldn't pronounce her name properly
